# post transaction details to remote server (aspx vb)

Tags: vb.net

Please i need serious help, i am stock in the middle of my application.
I want to post transaction details to https://stageserv.interswitchng.com/test_paydirect/pay

Here is my code

```
Protected Sub btnPay_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnPay.Click
    'GET EVENT ID
    EventID = Request.QueryString("eid")
    'CALL SHA512
    Dim SHA512_hash As String = UCase(SHA512Cri(lblTrackingNo.Text & EventID & CustID & AppAmount & "http://www.siteredirecturl.com/get_resp.aspx/AC43543FA32234HB23423AFH843535"))

    Dim url As Uri = New Uri("https://stageserv.interswitchng.com/test_paydirect/pay")
    Dim postData As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder()
    postData.Append("product_id=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(EventID) + "&")
    postData.Append("pay_item_id=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(CustID) + "&")
    postData.Append("amount=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(AppAmount) + "&")
    postData.Append("currency=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode("566") + "&")
    postData.Append("site_redirect_url=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode("http://www.siteredirecturl.com/get_resp.aspx") + "&")
    postData.Append("txn_ref=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(lblTrackingNo.Text) + "&")
    postData.Append("hash=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(SHA512_hash))

    Dim myWebRequest As HttpWebRequest = TryCast(WebRequest.Create(url), HttpWebRequest)
    myWebRequest.Method = "POST"
    Dim byteArray As Byte() = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData.ToString())
    myWebRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    myWebRequest.ContentLength = byteArray.Length
    Dim dataStream As System.IO.Stream = myWebRequest.GetRequestStream()
    dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length)
    dataStream.Close()
End Sub
```

the server will perform a POST request to the "site_redirect_url" provided in my code that i posted to the server but it is not redirecting to "site_redirect_url".

Comment: You need to redirect the current request to Pay Direct's before they'll redirect the use back to your site. (An HTTP request from your server to their's does not touch anything on your client's browser.)

Comment: @Richard is correct.  Other payment providers I've dealt with have provided means to do a server side integration if that's what you want, but otherwise this should just be a normal form within the user's browser.  Assuming this is even a web application of course... if it's not, then yes - you want to be looking to see if there's an alternative means of integration with them, as this approach is not optimal

Comment: do u mean i should redirect like this; response.redirect("https://stageserv.interswitchng.com/test_paydirect/pay")

Comment: with html form, it works but i want do it in code behind; see html - <form name="form1" action="https://stageserv.interswitchng.com/test_paydirect/pay" method="post">
<input name="productid" type="hidden" value="21"/>
<input name="transactionreference" type="hidden" value="TRS100-633176"/>
<input name="amount" type="hidden" value="300000 "/>
<input name="site_redirect_url" type="hidden" value="http://www.siteredirecturl.com/get_resp.aspx "/>
<input name="hash" type="hidden" value="F6FF2E22F99D93DDDA52D71811FD92B3"/>
<input id="Submit1" type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>